# Where can I find a working example for Serial/UART reading with Universal Windows Application?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uart

The closest example to working I found was this: https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/SerialUART/CS .
But this one is verry buggy when reading.

Video: http://sendvid.com/zsc1o78p

I'm using this simple arduino code for testing.

```
int x = 0;    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop() {     
  x++;
  Serial.println("Halloooooooo" + String(x));     
  delay(300);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: As it stands, this question is ripe for closure, because you are asking about off-site resources with no mention of a specific programming issue, other than [some offsite resource] is "verry buggy". There might be specifics in the video, but these should be stated in your question, not as a link to yet another 3rd party resource. You should concentrate on a code related issue, not a request for 3rd party resources.

Comment: I'm asking for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by reducing the 
**serialPort.ReadTimeout**  .